# Swift - Have an unknown case for enum decoded from json string that is not included in cases

Tags: json, swift, enums, decodable

For a given JSON like below:

```
{
    "store": {
        "animals": [
            {
                "type": "dog"
            },
            {
                "type": "cat"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I can parse it with enum for `type` like following:

```
final class AnimalStore: Decodable {
    let store: Store
}

extension AnimalStore {
    struct Store: Decodable {
        let animals: [Animal]
    }
}

extension AnimalStore.Store {
    struct Animal: Decodable {
        let type: AnimalType?
    }
}

extension AnimalStore.Store.Animal {
    enum AnimalType: String, Decodable {
        case dog = "dog"
        case cat = "cat"
        //case unknown = how such a case could be implemented?
    }
}
```

And also since it is optional; it would work fine if `type` key value pair would be missing from json.

But I would like to have another case, lets call it `unknown` so that if any given type is not dog or cat (string being something else),type would be initialised as unknown. Right now it crashes if a type, other than dog or cat is given.

How initialising with another type other than the ones given can be implemented with enum?

In other words, for a given type like: `"type": "bird"` I would like `type` to be initialised as `unknown`.

Comment: I searched for such a question but couldn't find it, thanks for pointing out duplication @LeoDabus

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add the enum case with a string, you may as well use `"unknown"`.

To convert non-matching strings to unknowns, you have to manually implement `init(from decoder: Decoder)` at some point, either in your Animal or in AnimalType. I'd favour using AnimalType so that you don't have to manually decode any of the other properties of Animal.

```swift
enum AnimalType: String, Decodable {
    case dog = "dog"
    case cat = "cat"
    case unknown = "unknown"

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        let string = try container.decode(String.self)
        self = AnimalType(rawValue: string) ?? .unknown
    }
}
```

If you did it in `Animal`, you'd need something like:

```swift
// Decode everything else...
type = try? decoder.decode(AnimalType.self, forKey: .type) ?? .unknown
```

Comment: Implemented in AnimalType directly, working fine. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to allow some alternative to your enum values you may use something like this:

```
enum Alt<S, A> {
    case standard(S)
    case alternative(A)
}

extension Alt: Decodable where S: Decodable, A: Decodable {
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        if let standard = try? container.decode(S.self) {
            self = .standard(standard)
        } else if let alternative = try? container.decode(A.self) {
            self = .alternative(alternative)
        } else {
            throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(
                Self.self,
                DecodingError.Context(codingPath: container.codingPath, debugDescription: "")
            )
        }
    }
}
```

And then change `AnimalStore.Store.Animal` declaration to this:

```
extension AnimalStore.Store {
    struct Animal: Decodable {
        let type: Alt<AnimalType, String>?
    }
}
```

Now it will try to decode it as `AnimalType` first and then, if fails will decode it as `alternative` type. So you can keep the value of the strings not in your enum.

---

EDIT: Or in situations when `alternative` is `RawValue` of `standard` you may use something like this:

```
enum RawBox<T>: RawRepresentable where T: RawRepresentable {
    typealias RawValue = T.RawValue

    case packed(T)
    case raw(RawValue)

    init(rawValue: Self.RawValue) {
        if let packed = T(rawValue: rawValue) {
            self = .packed(packed)
        } else {
            self = .raw(rawValue)
        }
    }

    var rawValue: T.RawValue {
        switch self {
        case .packed(let packed):
            return packed.rawValue
        case .raw(let raw):
            return raw
        }
    }
}

extension RawBox: Decodable where RawValue: Decodable {
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        let raw = try container.decode(RawValue.self)
        self.init(rawValue: raw)
    }
}

extension RawBox: Encodable where RawValue: Encodable {
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        try container.encode(self.rawValue)
    }
}
```

…

```
extension AnimalStore.Store {
    struct Animal: Decodable {
        let type: RawBox<AnimalType>?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try with this

```
extension AnimalStore.Store {
  struct Animal: Decodable {
    let type: AnimalType?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
      case type
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
      let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
      type = try? values.decode(AnimalType.self, forKey: .type) ?? .unknown
    }
  }
}

extension AnimalStore.Store.Animal {
  enum AnimalType: String {
    case dog
    case cat
    case unknown
  }
}
```